# ANTLR4 Error: Exception in thread "main" java

Tags: java, antlr4, antlrworks2

I follow instruction `"Getting Started with ANTLR v4"` with simple grammar, no problem with other instruction. But I have one problem.

Except, I'm starting run

> grun Expr prog -gui

But show this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:166)
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:142)
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 2).
>       at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNSimulator.deserialize(ATNSimulator.java:114)
>       at ExprLexer.(ExprLexer.java:64)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with version 3 (expected 2).
>       ... 8 more

Anyone have an Idea? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Case closed. Few day before, I download 4.0 version actually. But I don't know if later I download the latest version. because after few a day, I download again to replace 4.0 version, some part has error in javac command. Unexpected, I download 4.1 version. Classical issue in export CLASSPATH, ~/.bash_profile has been updated.

Comment: Try stable version... that's it